# How to Create Testable DE from Existing Filtered DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automation

Have some filtered DE's from Synchronized DE's. I need to test these audiences and would like to create filtered/duplicate's for testing as a snapshot in time to test. The issue with these filtered DE's is they are created using a long set of automations and update daily causing them to not be testable due to requirement of static DE's.

Tried:

1. Unable to create DE from existing (these filtered DE's don't show up in their folder when doing this process)
2. Unable to do the simple create copy from Contact Builder under these DE's (option not there)
3. Other than setting up the complex automations that make these to run only once, is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you need a one-time snapshot of a filtered DE?
If that's a one-off thing, replicate the filter (manually) using email studio into another DE for your test.

Filtered DEs always copy the schema of their "parent" DE so all you need to do is ensure you set the exact same filter conditions. I hope this isn't "stating the obvious", but since you never mention it:

Email Studio > Subscribers > Synchronized Data Extensions > Filter Icon

[image]

Set your filter and "Save & Build" - the resulting DE then can be refreshed (where the filter is now, you'll see a "refresh" symbol for the filtered DE). That way the refresh can (in fact: has to) be done manually.